# why the page is redirecting to the one in action attribute without completion of the form?

Tags: php, javascript

my javascript code is below:

```
<script>
    function check(){
        if(document.getElementById("1").value=="") {
            alert("enter 1st value");
            document.getElementById("1").focus();
            return;
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("2").value=="") {
            alert("enter 2nd value");
            document.getElementById("2").focus();
            return;
        }
        return(true);
    }
</script>
```

my html page is

```
<form action="home.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="1"></input>
    <input type="text" id="2"></input>
    <input type="text" id="3"></input>
    <input type="submit"onclick="check()"></input>
</form>
```

when I left intentionally on of the input fields empty, it is focusing but immediately redirecting to home.php page without proceeding further for input value.

Answer (score 0):

You return void in the check function. If you return false submitting of the form halts.

```
<script>
    function check(){
        if(document.getElementById("1").value==""){
            alert("enter 1st value");
            document.getElementById("1").focus();
            return false; // <<<< CHECK THIS LINE;
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("2").value==""){
            alert("enter 2nd value");
            document.getElementById("2").focus();
            return false; // <<<< CHECK THIS LINE
        }
        return(true);
    }
</script>
```

// Edit
An input element is a so-called self-closing tag. Correct syntax is:

```
<input type="text" name="some_name" value="" />
```

And a submit button should be defined as:

```
<button type="submit">Button text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your question like below

```
function check(){
     if(document.getElementById("1").value==""){
        alert("enter 1st value");
        document.getElementById("1").focus();
        return false;
     }
     else if(document.getElementById("2").value==""){
        alert("enter 2nd value");
        document.getElementById("2").focus();
        return false;
     }
return(true);
}
```

if your function return false then it will prevent the form to be posted.
so inside the if condition returning false.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function check(){
                if(document.getElementById("1").value==""){
                    alert("enter 1st value");
                    document.getElementById("1").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                else if(document.getElementById("2").value==""){
                    alert("enter 2nd value");
                    document.getElementById("2").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
       </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form action="test.html" method="get">
          <input type="text" id="1"></input>
          <input type="text" id="2"></input>
          <input type="text" id="3"></input>
          <input type="submit"onclick="return check()"></input>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return false` in order for the submit to get cancelled.

```
<form action="home.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="1"></input>
    <input type="text" id="2"></input>
    <input type="text" id="3"></input>
    <input type="submit"onclick="return check()"></input> <!--Notice the return here-->
</form>

function check()
{
    if(document.getElementById("1").value=="")
    {
        alert("enter 1st value");
        document.getElementById("1").focus();
        return false;//return false instead of void
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("2").value=="")
    {
        alert("enter 2nd value");
        document.getElementById("2").focus();
        return false;//return false instead of void
    }
    return true;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4wmw/)

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking for third field whether it is empty or not.... Then how will this be stopped if it is empty?

It goes with out getting tested

Also usage `return false` is needed in order to prevent the page from going on, because it tells the browser to reset such actions.

And then use `return check()` instead
Change to

```
  <html>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function check(){
            if(document.getElementById("1").value==""){
                alert("enter 1st value");
                document.getElementById("1").focus();
                return false;
            }
            else if(document.getElementById("2").value==""){
                alert("enter 2nd value");
                document.getElementById("2").focus();
                return false; 
            }
            else if(document.getElementById("3").value==""){
                 alert("enter 3nd value");
                document.getElementById("3").focus();
                return false; 
            }
            return(true);
        }

    </script>
    <form action="home.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="1"></input>
    <input type="text" id="2"></input>
    <input type="text" id="3"></input>
    <input type="submit"onclick="return check()"></input>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="home.php" method="get" onSubmit="return check();">
<input type="text" id="1"></input>
<input type="text" id="2"></input>
<input type="text" id="3"></input>
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```